# Format API response data into desired format in javascript

Tags: javascript, formatting, format

I get the below response from an API call, which i have just assigned to a variable `finalUpdate` for working.

```
var finalUpdate = {
  creator: {
    "firstName": "Cruise",
    "lastName": "Tom",
    "email": "tom.cruise@abc.com"
  },
  field: [{
      key: 'Car',
      value: {
        "tom.cruise@abc.com": {
          "userType": "responser",
          "data": [{
            "id": "98d0c05a-cd58-43b6-9465-370871a1b5ad",
            "data": {
              "value": "FORD FIESTA "
            }
          }],
          "time": 1631637403438
        }
      },
      editable: 'true',
      type: 'inputbox'
    }, {
      key: 'Car',
      value: {
        "tom.cruise@abc.com ": {
          userType: "responser",
          data: [{
            id: "98d0c05a-cd58-43b6-9465-370871a1b5ad",
            data: {
              value: "BMW 116i"
            }
          }],
          time: 1631610481102
        }
      },
      editable: "true",
      type: "inputbox"
    },
    {
      key: 'Car',
      value: {
        "tom.cruise@abc.com ": {
          userType: "responser",
          data: [{
            id: "98d0c05a-cd58-43b6-9465-370871a1b5ad",
            data: {
              value: "Audi Q8"
            }
          }],
          time: 1631610489632
        }
      },
      editable: "true",
      type: "inputbox"
    }
  ],
  response: [{
      "email": "tom.cruise@abc.com",
      "firstName": "Cruise",
      "lastName": "Tom",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "email": "tom.cruise@abc.com",
      "firstName": "Cruise",
      "lastName": "Tom",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "email": "tom.cruise@abc.com",
      "firstName": "Cruise",
      "lastName": "Tom",
      "id": 1
    }
  ],
  title: 'EEEEE WORK',
  collectionID: '1234'
}
```

I am trying to modify the above result to the**desired output** as seen below: Background of this data would be, I have 1 user, who has modified a data field 3 times, the user value can be seen in the attribute `value`.

```
//Final Formatted Output needed
{
  'tom.cruise@abc.com': [{
    key: 'Car',
    value: {
      "id": "98d0c05a-cd58-43b6-9465-370871a1b5ad",
      "data": {
        "value": "FORD FIESTA "
      }
    },
    editable: 'true',
    type: 'inputbox',
    time: 1631637403438
  }],
  'tom.cruise@abc.com': [{
    key: 'Car',
    value: {
      "id": "98d0c05a-cd58-43b6-9465-370871a1b5ad",
      "data": {
        "value": "BMW 116i "
      }
    },
    editable: 'true',
    type: 'inputbox',
    time: 1631610481102
  }],
  'tom.cruise@abc.com': [{
    key: 'Car',
    value: {
      "id": "98d0c05a-cd58-43b6-9465-370871a1b5ad",
      "data": {
        "value": "Audi Q8 "
      }
    },
    editable: 'true',
    type: 'inputbox',
    time: 1631610489632
  }],
}
```

My workcode is shown below, I tried getting the closest result but not able to map user to the value as desired.....

```
var resp = finalUpdate.response;
var emails = [];
var fields = [];

//Fetching the emails to match with field List
resp.map((x) => {
  emails.push(x.email)
});
console.log("Email ==>", emails);

//Checking the field length
console.log("Field length", finalUpdate.field.length);

finalUpdate.field.map((x) => {
  var data = x.value;
  var keys = Object.keys(data)
  console.log("data", data);
  console.log("keys", keys);

  //For each iteraton map corresponding email with field value email and format output as shown below
  keys.map((key) => {
    console.log("data of specifi user", data[key]);
    fields.push({
      key: x.key,
      value: data[key].data,
      time: data[key].time,
      editable: x.editable,
      type: x.type
    });

  });
});

console.log("Fields", fields);
```

However I am unable to map the email or user to the result. How do i add the user to the specific result obtained. The result of the above code is as follows:

```
"Fields" Array [Object { key: "Car", value: Array [Object { id: "98d0c05a-cd58-43b6-9465-370871a1b5ad", data: Object { value: "FORD FIESTA " } }], time: 1631637403438, editable: "true", type: "inputbox" }, Object { key: "Car", value: Array [Object { id: "98d0c05a-cd58-43b6-9465-370871a1b5ad", data: Object { value: "BMW 116i" } }], time: 1631610481102, editable: "true", type: "inputbox" }, Object { key: "Car", value: Array [Object { id: "98d0c05a-cd58-43b6-9465-370871a1b5ad", data: Object { value: "Audi Q8" } }], time: 1631610489632, editable: "true", type: "inputbox" }]
```

Comment: The output you're asking for is not possible. Objects cannot have duplicate keys. Consider an array of objects instead.